# RotateAnimation lags when behind ImageView with alpha

Tags: android

I have the next `RotateAnimation`.

```
private RotateAnimation createImageRotatingAnimationInfinite(ImageView imageView) {
    RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, imageView.getWidth() / 2, imageView.getHeight() / 2);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setDuration(ROTATE_DURATION);
    return animation;
}
```

And the next layout:

```
...
<!--ROTATING BACKGROUND-->
<com.bipfun.nightlight.customviews.SquareHImageView
    android:id="@+id/a_main_rotating_bckgnd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/rotating_bckgnd_default"/>

<!--LIGHT BACKGROUND-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/a_main_light_bckgnd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/bckgnd_stars_light"/>
...
```

I set the animation to the `a_main_rotating_bckgnd` and when i move my finder upwards/donwards across the screen I modify the `alpha` value of `a_main_light_bckgnd`. The thing is that with any `alpha > 0`, the rotating background behind it lags like crazy. It happens on just a number of devices, like HTC One, Samsung S3, Samsung Note II.

The **APIs** differ, one's 4.1.2, 4.3 and 4.4.2. It can't be the API as on other devices with similar APIs it works. They've all got **`xhdpi`** screens, but I've tried it with small images for the background, and they still lag.

I can't seem to figure this out. I need an image in the front, as it needs to be a bitmap. I also have a simple `View` to which i set the **background color** to something like `#50000000` (so 50 for the alpha), but that doesn't seem to affect the rotation animation.

Any ideas how to approach this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that all 3 devices were using `xhdpi` drawables. By mistake i removed the background of the `Fragment` and i observed it no longer lagged. So i shifted everything around. Moved the images from `hdpi` -> `xhdpi`, `xhdpi` -> `xxhdpi` and everything worked after that. It appears it coudln't handle too many large images on screen at once.

Comment: I made a similar mistake. I had a png in mdpi. I was doing scale and alpha animation of a view that's over this image. When I moved the png to xxxhdpi the animation became smooth.